# Configuring Connection Pool in Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary

Tags: sql-server, enterprise-library, connection-pooling

I am using Data Access Application Block from Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary and am finding the online documentation for this aging component lacking.

I'm having an issue with connection pooling and I want to review/adjust the settings for it. However, nothing seems to be mentioned about this in the configuration of the connection string, which is where I would expect it to be configured.

```
<connectionString name="Sql Connection String">
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="database" value="DB name" isSensitive="false" />
        <parameter name="password" value="xxx" isSensitive="true" />
        <parameter name="server" value="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" isSensitive="false" />
        <parameter name="user id" value="xxxxxxxx" isSensitive="false" />
    </parameters>
</connectionString>
```

Can anyone tell me how I configure connection pooling for this component? Am I even right that is configured in the config file?

I know there is a Windows Forms tool available in connection with Microsoft.Practices.EnterprisesLibrary but I don't have access to this, so I need the direct config file solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using file based configuration then Enterprise Library uses the `connectionStrings` configuration section:

```
<connectionStrings>

    <add
        name="Sql Connection String" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        connectionString="server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;database=DB name;
Integrated Security=false;User ID=xxxxxxxx;Password=xxx;Pooling=true;
Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=20;" />

</connectionStrings>
```

If you are using [fluent configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664363%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx#fluent_api_dataaccess) it would look something like this:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationSourceBuilder();

builder.ConfigureData()
       .ForDatabaseNamed("Sql Database")
         .ThatIs.ASqlDatabase()
         .WithConnectionString("server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;database=DB name;
Integrated Security=false;User ID=xxxxxxxx;Password=xxx;Pooling=true;
Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=20;")
         .AsDefault();

var configSource = new DictionaryConfigurationSource();
builder.UpdateConfigurationWithReplace(configSource);
EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current 
  = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer(configSource);
```

Comment: Is this in the same section as the example I provided or is it in the .NET "default" connectionStrings config section? How do I tell Enterprise Library which one to use? Is there are hierarchy?

Comment: This seems to be working, although I have not been able to completely confirm it as of yet.

Comment: CLR Profiler showed a much healthier memory timeline when I made this change to my service.